# How to access QGis::UnitType enum from a standalone python application

Tags: qgis

I have a standalone app that imports the qgis.core libraries to do the GIS mapping stuff. I have a QgsMapCanvas for map display. Now, I can get back the mapUnits() of the map display, but it comes back as a number, such as {UnitType 2}, I know it is the number in the QGis::UnitType enum type, so the question is how to get the name of the UnitType in QGis from this unit type number that I got from the map canvas?

I know I can hard code them in, but it would be better to go to where it is defined. below is the code snippet. the 'mapUnits' call will give you a number, I would like to have the name of that QGis::UnitType enum.

```
<code>
fileInfo = QFileInfo(raster)
path = fileInfo.filePath()
baseName = fileInfo.baseName()
layer = QgsVectorLayer(path, baseName)
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
if layer.isValid() is True:
    layer.dataProvider().crs().mapUnits()
</code>
```

Comment: Show your code please

Comment: @bc004346, see my edits with the code snippet

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```py
print(QgsUnitTypes.toString(myUnits))
```

Be just aware that units enum have been renamed and moved out of `QGis` to `QgsunitTypes` class in version 3.x:

- 2.x: QGis::UnitType
- 3.x: QgsUnitType::DistanceUnit

Comment: the problem is that I can't get access to the 'QGis' namespace. That is the root of the problem.

Comment: Which version of qgis do you use?

Comment: I forgot to mention this is a standalone PyQGis application, so I am not running script from inside installed QGis.

Comment: Still the information matters, the API is different in 2.x than in future 3.x. Can you show the whole code with the import (i.e. a minimal example)?

Comment: I edited the answer, it is totally feasible, sorry. Although, it is not normal you cannot access to QGis module, it would be easier to see your code.